# Laravel Argument 1 passed to

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to do my coding, but I ran into this issue. Thing is, I did it exactly the same like my first code, but it's working there.

> ErrorException in CoinflipController.php line 115: Argument 1 passed
>   to App\Http\Controllers\CoinflipController::CoinflipToJson() must be
>   an instance of App\Models\Game\Coinflip\Coinflip, instance of
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\site\app\Http\Controllers\CoinflipController.php on
>   line 104 and defined

Coinflip File

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Game\Coinflip;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Coinflip extends Model {
    const STATUS_ACTIVE     = 0;
    const STATUS_ROLLING    = 1;
    const STATUS_ENDED      = 2;

    protected $table = 'coinflip';    
    protected $fillable = [
        'status',
        'winner_steam_id',
        'winner_probability',
        'winner_value',
        'hash',
        'ticket',
        'seed',
        'player1',
        'player1_side',
    ];
    protected $dates = [ 'draw_at' ];
    protected $casts = [
        'winner_steam_id' => 'string',
        'winner_probability' => 'float',
        'winner_value' => 'float',
        'ticket' => 'double'
    ];

    public function entry(){
        return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\Game\Coinflip\CoinflipEntry', 'coinflip_id' );
    }

    public function winner(){
        return $this->hasOne( 'App\User', 'steam_id', 'winner_steam_id' );
    }

    public function getCommissionValue(){
        $val = 0;
        foreach( $this->entry as $entry ){
            foreach( $entry->item as $item ){
                if ( $item->status == CoinflipEntryItem::STATUS_COMMISIONED )
                    $val += (float)$item->price;
            }
        }
        return $val;
    }
}
```

CoinflipToJson Function  (From 1st line is the Error)

```
 public function CoinflipToJson( Coinflip $coinflip, $showExtra = false ){
        $canDeposit1 = $coinflip->value * 0.10 + $coinflip->value;
        $canDeposit2 = $coinflip->value - $coinflip->value * 0.10;
        $data = [
            'id' => $coinflip->id,
            'hash' => $coinflip->hash,
            'gameValue' => $coinflip->value,
            'canDeposit1' => $canDeposit1,
            'canDeposit2' => $canDeposit2,
            'skinValue' => 0,
            'skinCount' => 0,
            'timeStart' => $coinflip->created_at->getTimestamp(),
            'timeEnd' => $coinflip->draw_at ? $jackpot->draw_at->getTimestamp() : 0,
            'timeEndIn' => $coinflip->draw_at ? $jackpot->draw_at->getTimestamp() - time() : -1,
            'timeMax' => Setting::of('JackpotExtendTime', 15)->getValue(),
            'entry' => []
        ];

        if ( $showExtra ){
            $data['winningPercentage'] = $coinflip->ticket;
            $data['winnerId'] = $coinflip->winner_steam_id;
            $data['secret'] = $coinflip->seed;
        }

        foreach( $coinflip->entry as $entry ){
            $entryData = $this->entryToJson( $entry );
            $data['entry'][] = $entryData;
            $data['skinValue'] += $entryData['skinValue'];
            $data['skinCount'] += $entryData['skinCount'];
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

Code where I am calling it (Line 5)

```
public function current( Request $request ){
    $coinflip = $this->getCurrentGame();
    if($coinflip){
        $data = [
            'current' => $this->CoinflipToJson($coinflip)
        ];
        return response()->json($data);
    } else return response()->json(['error' => 'No Games']);
}
```

getCurrent Game Function

```
public function getCurrentGame(){
    $coinflip = Coinflip::where('status', Coinflip::STATUS_ACTIVE)->get();
    return $coinflip;
}
```

Comment: A little more example code in your question would make things easier for use to make anything other than a guess

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hello, I am sorry about that. I'll add pastebin links.

Comment: Noooooo. Paste code here not links to code

Comment: I have updated my first post. I can't add here that much code. I would have to type "more info" about my post then :/

Comment: Funny I can add it quite happily

Comment: Could someone please help me out?

Comment: What is the code for your `getCurrentGame()` function?

Comment: Can you share the getCurrentGame() function please

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I have edited my first post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `getCurrentGame()` method, the `get()` method always returns a `Collection`, even if there was only one record. If you query will only ever return one record, you can just change `get()` to `first()`, and it will return the record instance, instead of a `Collection`.

Comment: Little question, if I can't use get() then how could I get all values from table?

Comment: @AndremarGrim `get()` will return all the values from the table. The problem with your current code is that `CoinflipToJson()` is expecting a `CoinFlip` instance, and you're attempting to pass in a `Collection` of coin flips, because that is what is being returned from your `getCurrentGame()` method.

Comment: Hmm, but what I would have to change it to work with Collection?

Comment: @AndremarGrim That all depends on what your requirements are. I will assume that your json should actually be able to return an array of current games. In that case, leave your `getCurrentGame()` alone (keep it as `get()`), and then change `'current' => $this->CoinflipToJson($coinflip)` to something like `'current' => $coinflip->map(function ($item) { return $this->CoinflipToJson($item); })->all()`. This will loop through the items in your `$coinflip` collection and convert them using your `CoinflipToJson()` method.

Comment: Could you edit your first post, I'm so stupid that I can't "fix" problem with [].